# SFDC regular expression to catch the word with repeated characters

Tags: formula, regular-expressions

I am going to use the regular expression to catch the word with repeated characters (letter, digit, or underscore).
I found pretty interesting results during my testing.  If I am using apex code,  Matcher.matches() would not catch it, while Matcher.find() would return correct value.  If I am trying the REGEX() in the formula field, it never works out.
The pattern I am using is '(\w)\1+'.  Just wonder how to get REGEX() worked for this requirement.

```
//Pasted the Apex code for the reference.
String stringToMatch = 'abcccdefg';  // String stringToMatch = 'abcdefg';
Pattern p = Pattern.compile('(\\w)\\1+');
Matcher m = p.matcher(stringToMatch);
system.debug(m.find());
System.debug(m.matches());
if (m.find())
{
    system.debug('Duplicate character ' + m.group(1));
}
```

Any help would be truly appreciated.  Thank you very much in advance.

Regards,
Rong

Answer (score 1):

The formula would work, except that it automatically includes ^ and $ boundaries by default around the string. The solution is to add wildcard matches on either side of the expression. The following rule should work:

```
REGEX(Name, ".*(\\w)\\1+.*")
```

For matchers, you should ordinarily use `find()` if you expect multiple results. `matches()` instead considers the entire string. See [Using Match Operations](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_classes_pattern_and_matcher_matching.htm).

> - Match the Matcher object's entire input string against the pattern using the matches method
> - Match the Matcher object's input string against the pattern, starting at the beginning but without matching the entire region, using the lookingAt method
> - Scan the Matcher object's input string for the next substring that matches the pattern using the find method